# How to declare month to be within current_month only in presto

Tags: sql, presto

I have the following query in the WHERE clause to filter records within the current month only...

```
where date(date_id) >= date_trunc('month', current_date) and date(date_id) <= EOMONTH(date_trunc('month', current_date))
```

Does anyone know how to set it to exactly 1 month range (always current month)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`last_day_of_month()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#last_day_of_month) available in [Presto 331](https://prestosql.io/download.html).

```
WHERE date(date_id) BETWEEN date_trunc('month', current_date)
                        AND last_day_of_month(current_date)
```